# How to pass parameters to an external API via Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

I have rerouted an external API call using Firebase Functions and everything seems to be working just fine (I have the paid plan) however, I am not sure how to pass parameters from the client side. The code on the server side looks like this:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });
const { default: axios } = require("axios");

exports.news = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {
    var config = {
      headers: {
        "X-Api-Key": functions.config().news.key,
      },
    };
    axios
      .get(
        "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=usa&from=2021-08-27&to=2021-08-28&sortBy=popularity",
        config
      )
      .then((res) => {
        response.send(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        response.sendStatus(error);
      });
  });
});
```

What I will be passing from the client side is the from and to dates which currently are hard coded in the url. Just to make sure, am I doing it right to make an API call from the client side using the generated link from the Firebase Functions:
`https://us-central1-<PROJECT-NAME>.cloudfunctions.net/news/`?

Thanks in advance for all your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass those params as query parameters similar to the API call:

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'the_cloud_function_url?from=the_date&to=another_date'
});
```

These query parameters can be access by `request.query` in the Cloud function.

Alternatively, you can make a `POST` request from Axios (client-side) and pass the data in body:

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'the_cloud_function_url',
  data: {
    fromDate: '2021-08-27',
    toDate: '2021-08-29'
  }
});
```

This data can be read in cloud function using the `request` object:

```
exports.news = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const {fromDate, toDate} = request.body

  console.log(fromDate, toDate)

  // continue
})
```

Comment: Yes, it's working, thanks! I used `request.query` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Send data in body and handle the request.